# jQuery - Can't select "label" element with "for" attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select the text of the "label" element amongst a large document of similar elements differentiated by the value of the "for" attribute.

If trying to select it like so `$("label[for=cu1]").text()`

This is not working, nor is selecting the root element.

Here is the example node that contains the label w/ text I'm trying to select.  Please keep in mind that there are many other similar nodes, with only the "for" attribute differing (and the id of the input element, if that helps) ...

```
<div class="verticalfield">
  <label class="verticalfield" for="cu1">Custom 1</label>
  <input id="cu1" class="inputtext long" type="text" value="" maxlength="255" name="cu1">
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jaKKL/

Comment: @jameshuckabone - I don't have any problem with that fiddle either. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: That should work.. If this is the same structure for all the labels .. The you may also try this approach $('#cu1').prev('label').text() .. http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/vt2eA/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm going to venture a guess and say that you are trying to use `$("label[for=cu1]").text()` before that label has been loaded in the DOM.  Try something like this:

```
$(function () {
   //other important stuff

   var text = $("label[for=cu1]").text();
   //etc.
});
```

Comment: Gaaah.  It's the simple things in jQuery that I must re-learn to appreciate.  Thank you sir!

Comment: @JamesHuckabone it has nothing to do with jQuery, but JavaScript/HTML.  At that point in your code `document.getElementById('cu1');` would not return anything either.

Comment: I was referring to the document ready wrapper, but thank you for the clarification!